# GeoFire putting another marker on the source location if no user is found nearby

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I am making a ridesharing android app and using firebase and geofire. When I press the button "Find Sameway Rides" it shows me users who are in a radius of 700m near me. But when there is no user, it returns another marker(green marker) at my location(pink marker). I don't know what is wrong with my code. I tried a lot but the problem stays the same. I even requested Firebase Support for help but they were unable to rectify it. So please help.

Var. which you need to know

```
 private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
//for geofire
private DatabaseReference geoDatabase;
public GeoFire geoFire;
public GeoQuery geoQuery;

    // [START initialize_database_ref]
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    // [END initialize_database_ref]
    geoDatabase = mDatabase.child("/Ridedata/Geodatafrom/");
    geoFire = new GeoFire(geoDatabase);
```

Now here is what happens onbutton click

```
  // post data to server and show nearby rides
public void nowFindRide(View view) throws JSONException {
    //Sending user info to database...
    final String from = eetsource.getText().toString();
    final String to = eetdestination.getText().toString();
    final String when = leavetext.getText().toString();
    final String name = user_name.getText().toString();
    final String email = user_email.getText().toString();
    final String picture = profile_pic_url.getString("url");
    userAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    authCurrentUser = userAuth.getCurrentUser();
    final String uKey = authCurrentUser.getUid();
    double fromLat = currentLatLng.latitude;
    double fromLong = currentLatLng.longitude;
    if (fromLat == 0.0 && fromLong == 0.0) {
        fromLat = sourcelat;
        fromLong = sourcelong;
    } else {
        fromLat = currentLatLng.latitude;
        fromLong = currentLatLng.longitude;
    }
    final long uid = Id;

    // post data to server.
    final String uniqueKey = mDatabase.child("Ridedata").push().getKey();
    LocationData locationData = new LocationData(name, from, to, when, picture, email);
    Map<String, Object> dataValues1 = locationData.toMap();
    final Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
    childUpdates.put("/Ridedata/" + "/Ridedetail/" + uKey, dataValues1);
    geoFire.setLocation(uKey, new GeoLocation(fromLat, fromLong));
    geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(fromLat, fromLong), radius);
    geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onKeyEntered(final String key, final GeoLocation location) {
            geoDatabase.child("Geodatafrom").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    Log.d(TAG,"data change:"+ dataSnapshot);
                   // One nearbyUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(One.class);
                    setNearbyMarker(new LatLng(location.latitude,location.longitude));
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Log.d(TAG,"the read failed: " + databaseError.getMessage());
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onKeyExited(String key) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Key %s is no longer in the search area" + key);
        }

        @Override
        public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location) {
            Log.d(TAG,String.format("Key %s moved within the search area to [%f,%f]",
                    key, location.latitude, location.longitude));
        }

        @Override
        public void onGeoQueryReady() {
            Log.d(TAG,"All initial data has been loaded and events have been fired!");
        }

        @Override
        public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {
            Log.d(TAG,"There was an error with this query: " + error);
        }
    });
    mDatabase.updateChildren(childUpdates);

    // done flushing data into database.
}
```

Here is my database
[Firebase database for my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeZTw.png)
And a screenshot of the problem [Screenshot showing the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJQbm.png)

rules for Geofire

```
 "Geofire": {
    ".indexOn": "g"
  }
```

Comment: Which of the methods gets triggered that shouldn't be? If its `onKeyEntered`, you should be able to see what key triggers incorrectly.

Comment: When somebody is nearby it properly shows me that user location with a green marker.So at this point onKeyEntered and onDataChange works fine.And onKeyEntered , onDataChange is responsible for showing the nearby markers in my case.Do you think there is some problem with my geofire rules?Sir please i want this problem to go away.

Comment: You'll need to run the code in a debugger and see what key triggers `onKeyEntered`. Once you know *what* key triggers, you can hopefully figure out *why* it triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so i figured out how to resolve the issue

```
 geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onKeyEntered(final String key, final GeoLocation location) {

           if (key != uKey ){
               setNearbyMarker(new LatLng(location.latitude,location.longitude),key);

           }
         //   markerDestination.add(key);
        }

        @Override
        public void onKeyExited(String key) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Key %s is no longer in the search area" + key);

                Sorrydialog sorrydialog = new Sorrydialog();
                sorrydialog.showDialog(BliMaps.this);
                markerDestination.remove();

        }
```

and it worked like magic.Maybe it's not the perfect solution but it serves the purpose.